# Polymer neon-animation: Element is remains visible after animating

Tags: polymer-1.0, polymer-starter-kit

I downloaded the Polymer Starter Kit and am trying to animate an paper-element like so

```
        <section data-route="contact">
          <button on-click="_onButtonClick">Toggle</button>
          <my-dialog>
            <paper-material elevation="1">
              <h2 class="page-title">Contact</h2>
              <p>This is the contact section</p> 
            </paper-material>
          </my-dialog>
        </section>
```

my-dialog.html as follows:

```
<dom-module id="my-dialog">

  <template>

    <content></content>

  </template>
</dom-module>

<script>

Polymer({

is: 'my-dialog',

behaviors: [
  Polymer.NeonAnimationRunnerBehavior
],

properties: {

  opened: {
    type: Boolean
  },

  animationConfig: {
    type: Object,
    value: function() {
      return {
        'entry': [{
          name: 'slide-left-animation',
          node: this
        }],
        'exit': [{
          name: 'fade-out-animation',
          node: this
        }]
      }
    }
  }

},

listeners: {
  'neon-animation-finish': '_onAnimationFinish'
},

_onAnimationFinish: function() {
  if (!this.opened) {
    this.style.display = '';
  }
},

show: function() {
  this.opened = true;
  this.style.display = 'inline-block';
  this.playAnimation('entry');
},

hide: function() {
  this.opened = false;
  this.playAnimation('exit');
}

  });

</script>
```

The problem I'm facing is that after toggling the animation, my paper-element is squished and remains visible on screen. How do I make it not visible after animation? I've tried hardcoding `<paper-material hidden?=true>` but that also does not hide the element.

Comment: this.style.display = 'none'; ?

Comment: lol. Thanks that works. If you submit that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented, you simply need to change `this.style.display = 'none';`